# Feeding a batch of inputs to a Tensorflow lite model in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I trained a TensorFlow model using Python, and exported it as a TF lite model.
The input is a feature vector of 17 floats, the output is a single float score.
When I import the model using Tensor Flow Lite in C++, I get that the input shape is (1, 17, 1),
while the output shape is (1,1).

So, in C++ I am able to feed an input vector if size 17 and get the result.
In production I have multiple feature vectors, and I would like to feed many of them to TF, doing something similar to the Model.predict() method that exists in Python.
Is it possible? 
Has anyone ever tried to do the same?

So far I tried to reshape the input and output tensors, like in the code pasted below.
I cannot show the entire code because it relies on an internal library.
The code below tries to add new tensors, set them as inputs and output, and reshape them.
The problem is: when I require the shape, the results are not what I expect.

Finally, when I try to feed them with random values (not shown), the program crashes because I write out of its allocated tensors.
Any idea is welcome. 
Thanks

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
constexpr size_t NumFeatures{ 17};
constexpr size_t NumInputSamples{ 2};

const std::string& modelFilepath{ cliArgs.tfModelFilepath()};

std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model= tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(modelFilepath.c_str());
if (!model)
{
  TRACE_ERR1("BuildFromFile() failed.");
  return;
}

tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
tflite::InterpreterBuilder builder(*model, resolver);
std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
builder(&interpreter);
if (!interpreter)
{
  TRACE_ERR1("Invalid interpreter.");
  return;
}

if (kTfLiteOk != interpreter->AllocateTensors())
{
  TRACE_ERR1("Failed at allocating tensors.");
  return;
}

TRACE_DBG2("Number of tensors:", interpreter->tensors_size());
TRACE_DBG2("Number of nodes:", interpreter->nodes_size());
TRACE_DBG2("Num Inputs:", interpreter->inputs().size());
TRACE_DBG2("Input(0) name:", interpreter->GetInputName(0));
TRACE_DBG2("Num Outputs:", interpreter->outputs().size());

for (size_t indxInput=0; indxInput<interpreter->inputs().size(); ++indxInput)
{
  for (int indxDim=0; indxDim<interpreter->input_tensor(indxInput)->dims->size; ++indxDim)
  {
    TRACE_VAR2(indxDim, interpreter->input_tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]);
  }
}
for (size_t indxOutput=0; indxOutput<interpreter->outputs().size(); ++indxOutput)
{
  for (int indxDim=0; indxDim<interpreter->output_tensor(indxOutput)->dims->size; ++indxDim)
  {
    TRACE_VAR3(indxOutput, indxDim, interpreter->output_tensor(indxOutput)->dims->data[indxDim]);
  }
}

std::vector<int> inDims( {NumInputSamples,17,1});
std::vector<int> outDims;
outDims.push_back(NumInputSamples);
TfLiteQuantizationParams quant;
quant.scale=1.0f;
quant.zero_point=0;

std::vector<int> myIndexInTensors{};
myIndexInTensors.resize(NumInputSamples);

std::vector<int> myIndexOutTensors{};
myIndexOutTensors.resize(NumInputSamples);

THROW_OPERATION_FAILED_IFX( kTfLiteOk!=interpreter->AddTensors(NumInputSamples, myIndexInTensors.data()),
                            "AddTensors() failed.");
THROW_OPERATION_FAILED_IFX( kTfLiteOk!=interpreter->SetInputs(myIndexInTensors), "SetInputs() failed.");

for (const auto indxInput: myIndexInTensors)
{
  TRACE_VAR1(indxInput);
  THROW_OPERATION_FAILED_IFX( kTfLiteOk!=interpreter->SetTensorParametersReadWrite( indxInput,
                                                                                    kTfLiteFloat32,
                                                                                    "input",
                                                                                    inDims.size(),
                                                                                    inDims.data(),
                                                                                    quant),
                              "SetTensorParametersReadWrite() failed.");
}

THROW_OPERATION_FAILED_IFX( kTfLiteOk!=interpreter->AddTensors(NumInputSamples, myIndexOutTensors.data()),
                            "AddTensors() failed.");
THROW_OPERATION_FAILED_IFX( kTfLiteOk!=interpreter->SetOutputs(myIndexOutTensors), "SetOutputs() failed.");
for (const auto indxOutput: myIndexOutTensors)
{
  TRACE_VAR1(indxOutput);
  THROW_OPERATION_FAILED_IFX( kTfLiteOk!=interpreter->SetTensorParametersReadWrite( indxOutput,
                                                                                    kTfLiteFloat32,
                                                                                    "output",
                                                                                    outDims.size(),
                                                                                    outDims.data(),
                                                                                    quant),
                              "SetTensorParametersReadWrite() failed.");
}

if (kTfLiteOk != interpreter->AllocateTensors())
{
  TRACE_ERR1("Failed at allocating tensors.");
  return;
}

TRACE_DBG1("Requiring the shape................................................................");
TRACE_VAR1(interpreter->inputs().size());
for (size_t indxInput=0; indxInput<interpreter->inputs().size(); ++indxInput)
{
  for (int indxDim=0; indxDim<interpreter->input_tensor(indxInput)->dims->size; ++indxDim)
  {
    TRACE_VAR3(indxInput,indxDim, interpreter->tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]);
  }
}

TRACE_VAR1(interpreter->outputs().size());
for (size_t indxOutput=0; indxOutput<interpreter->outputs().size(); ++indxOutput)
{
  for (int indxDim=0; indxDim<interpreter->output_tensor(indxOutput)->dims->size; ++indxDim)
  {
    TRACE_VAR3(indxOutput, indxDim, interpreter->tensor(indxOutput)->dims->data[indxDim]);
  }
}
  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OUTPUT:

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): Number of tensors: 46 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): Number of nodes: 18 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): Num Inputs: 1 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): Input(0) name: conv1d_input 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): Num Outputs: 1 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxDim= 0 interpreter->input_tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 1 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxDim= 1 interpreter->input_tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 17 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxDim= 2 interpreter->input_tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 1 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxOutput= 0 indxDim= 0 interpreter->output_tensor(indxOutput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 1 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxOutput= 0 indxDim= 1 interpreter->output_tensor(indxOutput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 1 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxInput= 46 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxInput= 0 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxOutput= 48 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxOutput= 0 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): Requiring the shape................................................................ 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): interpreter->inputs().size()= 2 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxInput= 0 indxDim= 0 interpreter->tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 2 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxInput= 0 indxDim= 1 interpreter->tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 0 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxInput= 0 indxDim= 2 interpreter->tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 0 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxInput= 1 indxDim= 0 interpreter->tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 32 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): interpreter->outputs().size()= 2 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxOutput= 0 indxDim= 0 interpreter->tensor(indxOutput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 2 

[DBG] runInferenceOnRandomFeatures(): indxOutput= 1 indxDim= 0 interpreter->tensor(indxOutput)->dims->data[indxDim]= 32
```

Comment: Have I answered your question or something left unclear?

Answer (score 0):

TFLite interpreter has next flow when you need change input:

1. Change input shape
2. Allocate tensors
3. Set input (and output) sources
4. Run inference
5. Gather results

As I see you have:

```
if (kTfLiteOk != interpreter->AllocateTensors())
{
  TRACE_ERR1("Failed at allocating tensors.");
  return;
}

TRACE_DBG1("Requiring the shape................................................................");
TRACE_VAR1(interpreter->inputs().size());
for (size_t indxInput=0; indxInput<interpreter->inputs().size(); ++indxInput)
{
  for (int indxDim=0; indxDim<interpreter->input_tensor(indxInput)->dims->size; ++indxDim)
  {
    TRACE_VAR3(indxInput,indxDim, interpreter->tensor(indxInput)->dims->data[indxDim]);
  }
}
```

Allocation prior input change. Make allocation after input/output size change and you will be fine. See [details](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc/class/tflite/interpreter.html#classtflite_1_1_interpreter_1a706bb39102f98ff2abbdb5628fc823e0)